# Assignment of variables in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script to simulate the following problem:

File A contains some entries like

```
a  
b  
c
```

and File B contains

```
a  
g  
d  
t  
q  
c
```

the final file should have
(contents of file b which are not there in file a)

```
g  
d  
t  
q
```

I was trying something like this but it's not working:

```
for i in `cat b` ; do if[ (grep $i a) != $i ] then echo $i; done
```

Comment: Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code has some errors:

1. forgot the closure of if statement : fi
2. "grep $i a"  must be interpreted as a command , such as $(grep $i a) or `grep $i a`
3. You must add some characters around $(grep $i a) avoid empty string comparasion , such as ":" or something else, whatever.

Solution:

```
for i in `cat b` ; do if [ :$(grep $i a) != :$i ] ;then echo $i;fi; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the files and then use `comm`.  In `bash`:

```
comm -13 <(sort a) <(sort b)
```

This assumes you have a sufficiently recent `bash` (version 3.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 is not new enough; 4.1 is OK), and that your files are `a` and `b`.  The `<(sort a)` is process substitution; it runs `sort` on `a` and the output is sent to `comm` as the first file; similarly for `<(sort b)`.  The `comm -13` option suppresses the lines only in the first file (`1`, aka `a`) and in both files (`3`), thus leaving the lines only in `2` or `b`.

Your command:

```
for i in `cat b` ; do if[ (grep $i a) != $i ] then echo $i; done
```

shows a number of problems — four separate syntactic issues:

1. Space before `[`
2. Dollar before `(`
3. Semicolon before `echo`
4. `fi;` before `done`

Fixing them gives:

```
for i in `cat b`; do if [ $(grep $i a) != $i ]; then echo $i; fi; done
```

You could also use:

```
for i in `cat b`
do
    if grep $i a > /dev/null
    then : in both files
    else echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: Good answer, although it's not immediately obvious that you gave two separate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` and `B` is your files, it can be done by `diff`

```
diff A B | grep '^>' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pearl.260> cat file3
i
a
b
c
pearl.261> cat file4
a
g
d
t
q
c
pearl.262> nawk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' file3 file4
g
d
t
q
pearl.263>
```